# How to push into values into a stack from a text file

Tags: c++, stl, stack, ifstream, argv

I am trying to teach myself C++ with some programming assignments. 
Trying to learn using stacks but I am unsure how to push values from a txt file into a stack.

Let' say I have the following text file:

```
16 24 25 3 20 18 7 17 4 15 13 22 2 12 10 5 8 1 11 21 19 6 23 9 14
```

How would I use ifstream,and argv from the command line to push the values into a stack?

Did research and using this as help, but it may not be relevant:

[How to push data of different data types into a vector by reading from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715282/how-to-push-data-of-different-data-types-into-a-vector-by-reading-from-a-file)

Comment: The SO post you referenced seems to have almost everything you need. Replace the use of `std::vector` by `std::stack`.

Comment: @RSahu Shame it's full of C nonsense.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend as the linked posts accepted answer does. You might get well of with a simple [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) and `std::istream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started.

```
stack<int> data;
{
    ifstream file("file.txt");
    int i;
    while (file >> i)
    {
        data.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `push_back` on a stack. Its `push`